# MySQL "like" like functionality in Memcache

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I am trying to fetch some data from Memcache, but I want to fetch data where the text matches the keys, something as we have in MySql "LIKE" operator to fetch data.

Example:

```
Select * from TABLENAME where FIELDNAME like "%TEXT%";
```

Do we have a replacement for it in memcache ?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Memcache uses a hashing algorithm to store keys.

You could maintain an index to all of your stored keys and search those in order to find matching keys to your criteria. Using the [getAllKeys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.getallkeys.php) function might help.